# What is wrong with my program? It doesnt show any clock timer?

Tags: java

hey guys I have this problem. We have to make our own clock timer and I already followed the specific tasks but my program still doesn't display any timer:

```
public class DigitalClock {
  private int hr;
  private int min;
  private int sec;

  public void setTime(int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
  {
    if (0 <= hours && hours < 24)
      hr = hours;
    else 
      hr = 0;

    if (0 <= minutes && minutes < 60)
      min =  minutes;
    else 
      min = 0;

    if (0 <= seconds && seconds < 60)
      sec = seconds;
    else 
      sec = 0;
  }

  public int getHours()
  {
    return hr;
  }

  public int getMinutes()
  {
    return min;
  }

  public int getSeconds()
  {
    return sec;
  }

  public void printTime()
  {
    if (hr < 10)
      System.out.print("0");
    System.out.print(hr + ":");
    if (min < 10)
      System.out.print("0");
    System.out.print(min + ":");
    if (min < 10)
      System.out.print("0");
    System.out.print(sec);
  }

  public void incrementHours()
  {
    hr++;

    if (hr > 23)
      hr = 0;
  }

  public void incrementMinutes()
  {
    min++;
    if (min > 59)
    {
      min = 0;
      incrementHours();
    }
  }

  public void incrementSeconds()
  {
    sec++;
    if (sec > 59)
    {
      sec = 0;
      incrementMinutes();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can we see the main code, what does your program do if it doesn't print?

Comment: question is not clear can you please give brief explain..

Comment: why in method printTime you are using hr<10 , min<10 and sec<10? You can simply print the time.

Comment: @nishu I think OP wants to print time in two digits format only. Thats why he is adding `0` if value is less than 10.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might have missed main method in your code.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    DigitalClock clock = new DigitalClock();
    clock.setTime(22, 14, 10);
    clock.incrementHours();
    clock.printTime();

}
```

If I add main method to code then it gives output like:

```
23:14:10
```

**Edit1**
As @RC has mentioned in his comment you are comparing `min` while checking `sec` so you have to change it to:

```
if (sec < 10)
  System.out.print("0");
```

Comment: if `if (min < 10) System.out.print("0"); System.out.print(sec);` is corrected to `if (sec < 10) //...`

Comment: @RC Good Pickup. Edited in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the main mehod : 
You can have main method and startTimer method like :

```
public void startTimer(int noOfSeconds) throws InterruptedException {
         setTime(0, 0, 0);
          while(noOfSeconds>0) {
              incrementSeconds();
              Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
              printTime();
              noOfSeconds--;
          }
   }


  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
      DigitalClock dc = new DigitalClock();
      int noOfSeconds = 1000;
      dc.startTimer(noOfSeconds);

  }
```

It will run the timer for no of seconds you pass.

Comment: Why does it shows the error "cannot find symbol" under "DigitalClock = new DigitalClock"? I'm sorry Im just a beginner and I find java as really hard so I am practicing. Thanks for your help

Comment: Its Ok. It happens at start.Post your code where you are getting an error.